# How do I change ASP.NET MVC authentication after creation?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oauth, active-directory, windows-authentication

I currently have an MVC 5 App which uses Windows authentication, from the intranet template.  I would like to now expose this to internet users and utilize oauth.  It seems that many of the files in oauth walkthroughs are missing from my project.  Is there a nuget package I can use to refill the missing files that would have been in the "Individual Users" template, or do I really need to create a new project as OAuth and back fill Windows auth into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really simultaneously use both Windows Auth and Forms Auth (Individual User Accounts), with or without OAuth. There's hacky ways to invalidate what I just said, but they're just that: hacky. Really, the only real approach is go Forms Auth and then connect to LDAP manually to sort of proxy authentication from the domain to Forms Auth (basically, you'd have to create a local user account that represents a domain account).

Really, if you need to use simultaneous different forms of auth, the safest and easiest bet is to use separate projects and just share as much of the code as you can, with class libraries, Razor Generator for compiling views, etc. You'd of course have to host each project separately, but you could simply use a subdomain (i.e. internal.mysite.com vs www.mysite.com), or if you got your own network DNS server, you can even map internal requests vs external requests to the two different sites using the same domain.

Comment: Thanks, Chris.  I'm reorganizing the project as a forms based auth now, and doing the AD lookups within the app to retrieve a username if the user is in network.  I'll wait a bit before marking as answered to see if anyone else has some tricks.